How I can process authentication exceptions and basic HTTP500-like exceptions separetely in Spring Boot 3
I'm building an API using Spring Boot 3.0.1 with Spring Security, I've built out the security filter chain and use custom exception handler in it to process exceptions in authentication (for example when I get request without correct JWT token). But this handler processing all others exceptions (such as invalid agruments in query) by default and in situation when I try to process invalid request I getting 401-unauthorised exception from my handler by default instead of 500-internal server error.
What should I do for make my custom handler in FilterChain process ONLY authentication exceptions?
My SecurityChain config:
@Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(
                        exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint)
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/taskservice/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        ;

        return http.build();
    }

My custom exception handler:
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        LoginResponseError body = LoginResponseError.builder()
                .status(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)
                .error("Unauthorized")
                .timestamp(Instant.now())
                .message(authException.getMessage())
                .path(request.getServletPath())
                .build();
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // register the JavaTimeModule, which enables Jackson to support Java 8 and higher date and time types
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        // ask Jackson to serialize dates as strings in the ISO 8601 format
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS,false);
        mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
    }
}

My filter:
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {


        // try to get JWT in cookie or in Authorization Header
        String jwt = jwtService.getJwtFromCookies(request);
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if((jwt == null && (authHeader ==  null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))) || request.getRequestURI().contains("/auth")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        // If the JWT is not in the cookies but in the "Authorization" header
        if (jwt == null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authHeader.substring(7); // after "Bearer "
        }


        final String userEmail = jwtService.extractUserName(jwt);
        /*
           SecurityContextHolder: is where Spring Security stores the details of who is authenticated.
           Spring Security uses that information for authorization.*/

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(userEmail)
                && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.employeeUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)){
                //update the spring security context by adding a new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                context.setAuthentication(authToken);
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }

I tried to .requestMatchers("/error**").permitAll() but it leads to opposite situation: Im getting 500-internal server error errors for all errors, even for problems with authentication

why do you have a custom jwt filter, building custom security is bad practice. Why havnt you read the spring security docs and selected one of the built in security implementations that already comes with spring security? whats the point of having a security framework if you have no intention of using it?

@Toerktumlare Im new in Spring Security, just exploring now. Thank you for your advice! But now I need to resolve problem from my question at first, I like the way to use custom exceptionHandler but I need to process only authentication exceptions in it

if you are new is even more a reason to read the docs and learn best practices from the start. It is not advice. And you cant do what you want to do, since you have by writing custom security opted out of using the built in features. You either choose to work with the framework, or against it and you have chosen to work against it. Good luck

I had a similar problem, probably this will help somehow.
When throws an exception (you expect 500), the request is redirected
to the "/error" endpoint. From the point of view of your configuration of securityFilterChain this endpoint is only for authenticated (anyRequest().authenticated()).
So, you can add ignoring().requestMatchers("/error/**"), smth like
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {

    return (web) ->
            web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/error/**");
}

But it is was not enought.In my case I changed logic in my filter(but it was custom filter that extends OncePerRequestFilter, added override method doFilterInternal). It threw only 500 in case of failure.
Adding SecurityContextHolder.clearContext() helped me:
    try {
... token validation logic, etc
 } catch (Exception e) {
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext(); //  In case of failure. Guarantee user won't be authenticated
            }

But, i didn't use  exception handler class that you use.
Also I've commented ".anyRequest().authenticated());" when solved the problem, but may be for another reason, don't remember.

added code of my custom filter

Maybe you need to add a try-catch in "doFilterInternal". In case there is an error during token validation. Several approaches for catch-block:

Re-throw exception in catch-block (throw new ServletException(e)),  it will result in sending an HTTP status code 500 Internal Server Error to the clients. Probably now it happens.
Send custom response (response.setStatus(...))
Having the thrown exception handled by an existing exception handler using HandlerExceptionResolver  (resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException);) Probably it can help.


https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-exceptionhandler

thank you! Resolved my issue using p. 4 in baeldung.com/spring-security-exceptionhandler
